# How do I write a query that returns data not existing in the other table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables customers & transactions. I have made the following query:

```
SELECT convert(char(3), TxDate, 0) as Mth,customer.Name,transactions.Debit,transactions.AccountLink 
  from Customer join transactions
  ON transactions.Accountid=Client.customerid 
 WHERE Name not in 
(SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, DAY(GETDATE())-1));
```

I would like to get customer name from customer table that did not buy anything from the transaction table in the previous month (the whole month).

Comment: Writing in all caps is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do. Also, please ask an actionable question, and provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: use `not exists`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to get customer name from customer table that did not buy anything from the transaction table in the previous month(the whole month)

Use `NOT EXISTS`.  Something like this:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t
                  where t.accountid = c.customerid and  -- strange conditoin
                        datediff(month, t.transactiondate, getdate()) = 1
                 );
```